# function goes allways to else statement but never return what I want

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return JSON if else statetment true, but it doesnt return anything ...return input works fine, but else return originalplaylist not ..what I am doing wrong ? ..

here is my source code ..

```
function shuffle(playlist) {
  var orgplaylist = (<?php echo readmp3();?>);
  console.log(orgplaylist);
  console.log(playlist);
  var input = playlist;
  console.log(input);
  if (JSON.stringify(orgplaylist) == JSON.stringify(playlist)) {
    $(".random img").attr('src', 'img/loop.png');
    // for (var i = input.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    for (var i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

      input[randomIndex] = input[i];
      input[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
    return input;
  } else {
    $(".random img").attr('src', 'img/loopsilver.png');
    console.log(orgplaylist);
    return orgplaylist;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the `console.log()` statements return the value you expect?  Are you closing the opening bracket of the function (in the code you copied there's no closing bracket)?

Comment: yeea there is closing bracket ..console.log return what I want ....I rewrite my problem ..first time I click on shuffle the condition is true..and it return shuffled JSON, second time i click on shuffle it change the style but JSON object stay shuffled, and any other click goes to else statement ..I dont know why...

Comment: I think basically what's happening is that the second time you click on 'shuffle' the value `playlist` that gets passed in is the shuffled version from the previous press.  Therefore, orgplaylist is never equal to playlist, the second time around.

Comment: `playlist` and `input` are references to the same object, when you change one, the other is changed as well. Maybe that is the problem. I think you maybe want `input` to be a copy of `playlist` instead of a reference.

Comment: you mean copy by     JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToCopy) ?? @Titus

Comment: Yes, that will do it.